# Concat translated key on twing using symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to gererate the translation key that has to be translated and show at the template but is not working

```
<h2 class="text-withe">{{  'cover.title.'~product.id | trans | raw }}</h2>
```

this way it works, but I think it should work without create a variable

```
{% set title_key = 'cover.title.'~product.id %}
<h2 class="text-white">{{ title_key | trans | raw }}</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you put `|` it just look for the value before `|` all you have to do is use parentheses you show that you one translate all of that like this:

```
('cover.title.'~product.id)| trans | raw
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know it's expected behavior

you should try something like this:

`{{  ('cover.title.'~product.id) | trans | raw }}`

Without `()` it will translate `product.id` and concatenate with `cover.title.`